# Accessing custom helper methods in rails 3 migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, helper, rails-migrations

In rails 2 I had a lib/migration_helpers.rb file with methods for setting and dropping foreign keys in the db.
These methods were available in self.up and self.down in migration files by adding in the migration file

```
require 'migration_helpers'
```

at the top, and

```
extend MigrationHelpers
```

immediately after the class statement.

In rails 3 this does not work, and if i try to run a migration using set_foreign_key method from migration_helpers.rb the following error is thrown:

```
==  AddFkToArticles: migrating ================================================
-- set_foreign_key("articles", "book_id", "books")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `set_foreign_key' for #<AddFkToArticles:0x000001034a1f38>

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I already checked that in config/application.rb the autoload path is set to include lib.
The file is effectively required, because if i comment out the require statement then rails whines about the missing 'migration_helpers' file.

I suspect this is a scoping problem (rails 2 used "def self.up", rails 3 uses "def change")
but cannot imagine how to solve the problem (by now I simply copied the code in the migration file, just to check that it does what it should do).

Francesco

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what exactly you're trying to accomplish but here's some code that might give you a clue.

```
## lib/test_helper.rb
module TestHelper

  def my_table_name
    return :mytable 
  end

end
```

And then the migration:

```
## db/migrate/test_migration.rb
include TestHelper

class TestMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    create_table my_table_name
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table my_table_name
  end
end
```

Including this helper inside the Migration class doesn't work so it should be outside.

Comment: I had to add require File.expand_path('../../../lib/test_helper', __FILE__) to the top of my migration file. Without it, it wouldn't work.

Comment: You need to `extend TestHelper` inside the class if you want the mixin to work with your class methods (like up and down).